Fan Not Working on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (Works on Windows)
I recently set up a dual boot on my Lenovo LOQ laptop with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. The issue I'm facing is that the fan works perfectly in Windows, but it doesn't seem to work at all in Ubuntu. Here’s a summary of the steps I’ve taken and the outputs:
1. Checked Sensor Readings
I ran sensors after loading the coretemp module:
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +45.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +40.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
...
acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +27.8°C

2. Tried pwmconfig
I installed fancontrol and ran pwmconfig, but I got this message:
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed

3. Installed tlp
After installing tlp and starting it, the fan issue still persisted. Here’s the relevant output:
TLP started in battery mode (auto).

However, when I checked /etc/tlp.conf, it was empty.
The fan works properly on Windows
Has anyone experienced this issue with Lenovo LOQ or any other laptop? I’d appreciate any suggestions on how to get the fan working in Ubuntu without harming the hardware.
Thanks in advance! 
